# How do I get WPF KeyDown event to capture Enter Key when using a 128 barcode?

Tags: c#, wpf

How do I get WPF KeyDown event to capture Enter Key when using a 128 barcode?

In my textbox events I have:

```
    private void KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter!");
        }
    }
```

I scan the barcode and all characters and digits show but Key.Enter is not captured.

UPDATE:

The barcode generated works in Notepad as a Return Key. I found that when it is scanned Key.LeftCtrl is being captured instead of Key.Enter or Key.Return. I am using a WASP9500 barcode reader.

Comment: I think you've wrongly assumed that at the end of a 128 barcode you're going to get the enter key.  Try outputting each individual key that's being scanned, which looks like you might have already done.  Why not just capture Key.LeftCtrl if that's what you're ending with?

Comment: That is an option but I feel like that would be a small hack to the program where I would like the barcode to mimic the keystrokes exactly. Do you feel there is no way of the barcode generating Key.Enter? @oppassum

Comment: That's dependent on the reader you have. Sometimes you can do different options on them. You'd have to look at your manual to find out.

Comment: I'll read up in the manual...also thinking another problem is that the user can choose to use the keyboard as well, so what if they hit the LEFT CTRL button by accident. @oppassum